# Matching a non-breakable white space in IE7 and IE8 in Javascript

Tags: regex, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, whitespace, match

I want to replace white spaces in any relatively modern browser (thus for IE, version >= 7).

Thus given the string `"Hello world!"` we would do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Result: '" + "Hello world!".replace(/\s/g, '') + "'");
</script>
```

Which we would expect to output: `Result: 'Helloworld!'`

But in IE7 and IE8 though it fails using a non-breakable space like one of these: `&#160;` == `&nbsp;` == `\u00A0`

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Result: '" + String.fromCharCode(160).replace(/\s/g, '') + "'");
</script>
```

Will output `Result: 'Helloworld!'` in FF and IE >= 9 and `Result : ' '` in IE7 and IE8. What the hell?

This makes me wonder if this is the only exception? I could not find much information about this at all. Is there maybe a Regular Expression which removes all white spaces *including* the non breakable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
replace(/(?:\s|\xA0|&nbsp;|&#160;)+/g, '')
```

```
replace(/[\s\xA0]+/g, '')
```

Comment: Your original answer does not work. The `&nbsp;` is useless once the characters are encoded, which is the entire problem.

Comment: @Asad - In my original answer I have included `&nbsp;` and `&#160;` into pattern to insure solution works with any browser, even some that do not encode special characters.

Comment: No, you just included `\s` and the character sequence `&nbsp;` in your original answer. It is in your edits that you included the hex code, as well as the equally useless `&#160;`.